# Loop Through Pivot Tables And Remove Same Values

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, pivot-table

I am trying to loop through all pivot tables in a sheet and remove all values fields in them which have the same name: "Total Net Spend" and "% Split" (see picture for reference).

[image]

I am trying the below code but it will only work on the first pivot and won't loop through all of them. How do I edit the code so that it will remove "Total Net Spend" and "% Split" columns on all the pivot tables in the sheet?

```
Sub Loop_Pivots()

Dim PT As PivotTable, PTField As PivotField

Set PT = Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("Pivot1")
With PT
    .ManualUpdate = True
    For Each PTField In .DataFields
        PTField.Orientation = xlHidden
    Next PTField
    .ManualUpdate = False
End With
Set PT = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop through the `PivotTables` try another `for` `each` loop like this

```
Sub Loop_Pivots()

    Dim PT As PivotTable, PTField As PivotField
    For Each PT In Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables
        With PT
            .ManualUpdate = True
            For Each PTField In .DataFields
                PTField.Orientation = xlHidden
            Next PTField
            .ManualUpdate = False
        End With
    Next PT
    Set PT = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Just tried but an error pops up saying: unable to set the orientation property of the PivotField class...

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Loop_Pivots()

Dim PT          As PivotTable
Dim PTField     As PivotField

For Each PT In Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables

    With PT
        .ManualUpdate = True
        For Each PTField In .PivotFields '<-- loop through all pivot fields
            Select Case PTField.Name
                Case "Total Net Spend", "% Split"  '<-- if Field Name equals on of the 2 in this case
                    PTField.Orientation = xlHidden
            End Select
        Next PTField
        .ManualUpdate = False
    End With
    Set PT = Nothing
Next PT

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but nothing happens with this code... With the original code I was able to get rid of "Total Net Spend" and "% Split" on the first pivot but it wouldn't loop through the remaining pivots...

Comment: @Andrea  strange, worked for me. Does it return an error ?